# SQL GROUP BY with "default values"

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, mysql5

I'm trying to create `SELECT` statement with a `GROUP BY` clause, which should return "default values".

Imagine the following simple MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tracker` (
  `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

The table contains only one record:

```
INSERT INTO `tracker` (`date`, `customer_id`) VALUES('2010-05-03', 1);
```

After wards I'm executing the following SQL query:

```
SELECT DATE(`date`), COUNT(customer_id) FROM tracker
WHERE DATE(`date`) >= '2010-05-01' AND DATE(`date`) <= '2010-05-05'
GROUP BY DATE(`date`) ORDER BY DATE(`date`);
```

And get the expected result set:

```
+----+---------------------+-------------+
| id | date                | customer_id |
+----+---------------------+-------------+
|  1 | 2010-05-10 00:00:00 |           1 |
+----+---------------------+-------------+
```

However, I would like the result set to look like this:

```
+--------------+--------------------+
| DATE(`date`) | COUNT(customer_id) |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 2010-05-01   |                  0 |
| 2010-05-02   |                  0 |
| 2010-05-03   |                  1 |
| 2010-05-04   |                  0 |
| 2010-05-05   |                  0 |
+--------------+--------------------+
```

Is it possible to achieve this behavior?

Comment: There are quite a few duplicates with this same theme, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400759/sql-group-by-date-but-get-dates-w-o-records-too

Answer (score 3):

You could build a temporary table of the valid dates in the range and then incorporate that into your query - that's about the only way forward that I can immediately see...

Martin

Answer (score 3):

As Martin said, the best solution is to create a temp table with dates.

Then there's 2 approaches:

- Do an outer join with that temp table and do a `group by` on result, OR
- `group by` on the original table + `UNION select date,0 as count from date_table d where not exists (select 1 from customer c where c.date=d.date)`